# How to import python files on Google app engine project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I recently started playing with Google app engine (GAE) and I'm failing to do something very simple.

The GAE provides a `main.py` file which is where I'm trying to import a file I created `util.py`.

I saw some examples saying that you need to create a module for that in order to be able to include it.

So I did

```
main.py 
utilities/ 
    __init__.py 
    util.py
```

In `main.py` I imported `import utilities.util`, I still can't call the functions inside of util.py.

Any ideas where I could learn more about these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import utilities.util as myutil
myutil.function_name()  #Using the module name you can access the functions


from utilities.util import function_name()
function_name()
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.